# How to spawn a new Python child process in Node.js after the first one ends?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, spawn, spawning

I use the output of a Python script in my node.js app.

However, I need to query it another time (and, possibly, several times).

I cannot do this because the Python process ends and cannot be restarted. I tried to reassign the variable, but it doesn't work. How to launch the Python script again? Here is my code:

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
interval_data = [1,2,4,5,6,7],
interval_dataString = '';

var py = undefined

startPython()

py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  interval_dataString += data.toString();
  console.log(interval_dataString)
});
  

py.stdout.on('end', function(){

  console.log('Alpha Component =',interval_dataString);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    startPython()
  },1000)

});


function startPython() {
  py = undefined
  py = spawn('python', ['dfa.py'])
  py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(interval_data));
  py.stdin.end();
}
```

Here's the Python code:

```py
## compute_input.py

import sys, json, numpy as np

#Read data from stdin
def read_in():
    
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    #Since our input would only be having one line, parse our JSON data from that
    
    return json.loads(lines[0])
    
    #lines = "[1,2]" # for testing
    #return json.loads(lines) # for testing

def main():
    #get our data as an array from read_in()
    lines = read_in()

    #create a numpy array
    np_lines = np.array(lines)

    #use numpys sum method to find sum of all elements in the array
    lines_sum = np.sum(np_lines)

    #return the sum to the output stream
    print(lines_sum)

#start process
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you post your python code ? So i can test my example

Comment: Hey @Marc added my python code!

Answer (score 0):

You override the child process.
So you can no longer use the original object (event emitter).

Its simpler then you tought maybe :)

Just call/move the event emitter stuff inside the "start" function.
So every time you spawn the child, you use the new child object/event emitter.

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const interval_data = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const interval_response = [];

// use this as exit strategie
var should_restart = true;


function start() {

    // spawn python child
    let child = spawn("python3", ["dfa.py"]);

    // would be better to work on buffer objects
    // create on final child/python exit a string out of the buffer
    child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        interval_response.push(data.toString());
    });

    // listen for the close event
    child.on("close", () => {
        if (should_restart) {

            // feedback
            console.log("Alpha Component =", interval_response.join());

            setTimeout(() => {
                start();
            }, 1000)

        } else {

            // nope, not now!
            console.log("DIE!", interval_response);
        
            // Do what ever you want with the result here

        }
    });

    // write stuff to python child process
    child.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(interval_data));

}

start();


// let the programm run for min. 5sec
setTimeout(() => {
    should_restart = false;
}, 5000);
```

Tested with your python code.

```
node index.js
Alpha Component = 3

Alpha Component = 3
,3

Alpha Component = 3
,3
,3

Alpha Component = 3
,3
,3
,3

DIE! [ '3\n', '3\n', '3\n', '3\n', '3\n' ]
```

I thought you actually read in your python script from stdin. (And not only a dummy function)

But for the node part it should not make any difdrence.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 x64, node: v13.14.0, python: 3.6.9.

**EDIT**:

Created based on your python snippet, a script that reads from stdin and create a sum out of all numbers passed:

```py
import sys, json

def main():

    data = sys.stdin.read()
    data = json.loads(data)

    #print("debug:", data)

    chunks_sum = sum(data)

    #print("debug", chunks_sum)

    sys.stdout.write(str(chunks_sum))

#start process
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Modified start function:

```js
function start() {

    // spawn python child
    let child = spawn("python3", ["dfa.py"]);

    // would be better to work on buffer objects
    // create on final child/python exit a string out of the buffer
    child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {

        // since your python code just create
        // a sum of all numbers, store the 
        // returend stuff as number
        interval_response.push(Number(data));

    });

    // listen for the close event
    child.on("close", () => {
        if (should_restart) {

            // feedback
            console.log("Alpha Component =", interval_response);

            setTimeout(() => {
                start();
            }, 1000)

        } else {

            // nope, not now!
            console.log("DIE!", interval_response);

            // create sum of all sum chunks from python
            // not sure what you want to do with the "interval_response" array
            // just for demo purpose
            let sum = interval_response.reduce((pv, cv) => pv + cv, 0);

            console.log("Total sum", sum);

        }
    });

    // write stuff to python child process
    //child.stdin.write();

    child.stdin.end(JSON.stringify(interval_data));

}
```

Changed `child.stdin.write` to `child.stdin.end`, so does python now it can "start" and dosnt has to wait for more data.

*Note: i dont know how IPC/stdio "buffering" work. Perhaps you expirence some fishy things if you work with large data.*

More, we store the data from python that is writen to "stdout" as number in the array `interval_response`, since you just calculate the total sum of the data we write to "stdin".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in fact if we are reading the JS input in python the script doesn't work. I modified the python script above, please, check, it doesn't work with that modification for some reason... Do you know why? If I add `py.stdin.end();` it works, but only once.